# Capacitance of a System of Two Spheres

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity, capacitance

To explain more clearly, I am looking for how one would derive an expression for the capacitance of a system which consists of two conducting spheres of radius $a$ separated by a distance $d>2a$. I found the following solution on the Wikipedia article on Capacitance, however no explanation is given:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}\ = &\ {} 2 \pi \varepsilon a\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sinh \left( \ln \left( D+\sqrt{D^2-1}\right) \right) }{\sinh \left( n\ln \left( D+\sqrt{ D^2-1}\right) \right) }  \\
={}&{}2\pi \varepsilon a\left[ 1+\frac{1}{2D}+\frac{1}{4D^2}+\frac{1}{8D^3}+\frac{1}{8D^4}+\frac{3}{32D^5}+ \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{D^6} \right) \right] \\
={}&{} 2\pi \varepsilon a\left[ \ln 2+\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 2D-2\right) + \mathcal{O}\left( 2D-2\right) \right] \\
={}&{} 2\pi \varepsilon a \,\frac{\sqrt{D^2 - 1}}{\log(q)}\left[\psi_q\left(1+\frac{i\pi}{\log(q)}\right) - i\pi - \psi_q(1)\right]
\end{align}

I should also note the following substitutions which were made:

$$D=d/2a>1$$
$$q=D+\sqrt{D^2-1}$$

Any insight on the reasoning behind this derivation, in particular, where the first step with the hyperbolic sines comes from, would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is derived using the method of images in Smythe: Static and Dynamic Electricity; see https://archive.org/details/staticdynamicele0000smyt_e3w8/page/118/mode/2up?view=theater